# Ubuntu fails to install everytime while installing the grub can anyome shed some light?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, uefi, boot-repair

I had a dual booot with Windows 10 and elementary, I also have a SSD in which windows 10 was installed and elementary was installed on a HDD. When I tried to install the new elementary distribution by erasing the partition and creating a new one for the new OS the installation program crashed at the grub installation, saying it was a fatal error, so I've decided to try with Ubuntu 18.04.1 and the same thing happens. I always select the SSD as the boot device. I've already tried to recover the boot with boot-repair but it won't work, it says it can't solve the problem and exits. I'm not sure this is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong,but I searched in forums for some days now and I haven't found nothing that helps me yet, I'd accept gladly any orientation to install any linux distribution on my system. Thanks

I've already filled a bug report in the last failed installation and I'm linking it here, if there's a problem just point it out and I will edit acordingly

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/1800858

Answer (score 0):

boot up 18.04 using USB memory stick and pick option Try first ... once booted launch `gparted` and view all partitions ... each OS gets its own partition ... on partition you wish to destroy and replace with new install right click on that partion ... choose format `ext 4`  and also choose to mount that partition at `/` then commit that change hitting green checkmark in `gparted`

You can also do above while answering questions during a normal install ... when it asks to install `along side` etc hit Advanced option at bottom then do above steps

This will install your new OS ... once install finishes and you reboot this freshly installed OS will be the new default OS at grub menu so just hit enter

Enjoy !!!